# Grant access rights to one specific directory

Tags: linux, permissions, administration, raspberry-pi2

Since I am not that experienced with Linux this might be an easy, if not too simple question for you. Recently I met an old friend of mine and I want to exchange some files with him. In fact I could send the files by E-Mail or share them by Dropbox or something like that but I want to make use of Linux and my RaspberryPi.

Here, the RaspberryPi can be accessed via SSH and I want my friend to be able to access one specific directory. The one where I place the files.
I don't want him to mess around in the system. Ideally he should be able to only see this one directory.

Is it enough if I create a user and put the files in his home directory?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to do some research and learn how basic Unix file permissions work. This isn't a programming question and thus is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this introduction to permission management on Linux](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0090.php).

To answer your Question:

> Is it enough if I create a user and put the files in his home directory?

Yes, but it's not a perfect solution because the home folder of an user contains some subfolders.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After rethinking I think, what I really want is creating a ftp account, for which I found some interesting manuals.